# Accessing Modal Popup Extender defined in one ASCX page in another ASCX pages Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have two ASCX pages, call them `Page1` and `Page2`.

In the HTML of Page1, I define a `ModalPopupExtender`.  Now in the code behind on `Page2`, I'd like to do a `ModalPopupExtender.Show` when a button is clicked.

When I try to do this, I get an error stating the `ModalPopupExtender` doesn't exist in current context.  Is there a way to reference the `ModalPopupExtender` defined in `Page1` from `Page2` so I can control it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose your modal popup as a public property on your main page.

```
public class BasePage: System.Web.Ui.Page
{
    public ModalPopupExtender MyPopup
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myPopup;
        }
    }
}
```

In your ascx code behind cast `this.Page` to your page type.

```
public class Page1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((BasePage)this.Page).MyPopup.DoWhatEver();
    }
}
```